# WPF Canvas children rect box

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Is there any way to create a copy of canvas with the new canvas will be as a box of children elements of the first canvas ?

[image: first canvas]

first canvas

[image: second canvas]

second canvas

i want something like that i am showing in the second canvas.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you need.  Do you need two canvases, but one (the copy) contains copies of the children in the first canvas?  What is the difference between the two canvases?

Comment: the size of canvas and (canvas.top, canvas.left of each child element)

Comment: If I may ask, what do you plan on doing with these canvases?  I've implemented a solution, but am curious on its practical uses.  I do not believe there is a simple solution to your problem, unless the problem is tackled from a different approach.

Comment: I like your answer but it doesn't fit for me. i want to drawing on canvas and then move that "draw" to second canvas but keep only the area that i have some elements not the empty space. on those images i have background color so you can understand the location of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer with lines as children, but i want a better solution.

```
Point firstPoint = new Point(DrawCanvas.ActualWidth, DrawCanvas.ActualHeight);
Point endPoint = new Point(0, 0);
foreach (Line element in DrawCanvas.Children)
{

    double x = element.X1;
    double y = element.Y1;


    if (x < firstPoint.X)
        firstPoint.X = x;

    if (y < firstPoint.Y)
        firstPoint.Y = y;

    if (element.X2 > endPoint.X)
        endPoint.X = element.X2;

    if (element.Y2 > endPoint.Y)
        endPoint.Y = element.Y2;
}

double offsetX = firstPoint.X - 5;
double offsetY = firstPoint.Y - 5;


var children = DrawCanvas.Children.Cast<Line>().ToArray();
DrawCanvas.Children.Clear();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 111, 0));
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 111, 111));
rect.Width = endPoint.X - offsetX + 5;
rect.Height = endPoint.Y - offsetY + 5;
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);

newCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
newCanvas.Width = rect.Width;
newCanvas.Height = rect.Height;

foreach (Line element in children)
{
    Line newLine = element;
    newLine.X1 = element.X1 - offsetX;
    newLine.X2 = element.X2 - offsetX;
    newLine.Y1 = element.Y1 - offsetY;
    newLine.Y2 = element.Y2 - offsetY;

    newCanvas.Children.Add(newLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by deriving from `Canvas` and overriding [`OnVisualChildrenChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.onvisualchildrenchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

You must make changes public so that your copied `Canvas` (let's call it the target `Canvas`) can be properly updated.

What you want to do is fairly complex if you need to listen to changes for when the source canvas has children whose properties are updated.  In this case, you must again notify your target canvas of changes, which can be done by adding bindings.

## XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="437.042" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Height="213" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <local:ObservableCanvas x:Name="CanvasSource"
                VisualChildrenChanged="CanvasSource_VisualChildrenChanged">

                <!-- Add some elements -->
                <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"
                         Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Green"/>
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30"
                         Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Blue"/>
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="60"
                         Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Yellow"/>
            </local:ObservableCanvas>
        </Border>

        <Border Margin="148,228,148,10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Canvas x:Name="CanvasTarget" Loaded="CanvasTarget_Loaded"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At design time, this is the window:
[image: Window - Design Time]

In particular, notice the `VisualChildrenChanged="CanvasSource_VisualChildrenChanged"`.  This is how the changes are made public.  We handle these changes in the code-behind for the `MainWindow`.

## ObservableCanvas

```
//This class notifies listeners when child elements are added/removed & changed.
public class ObservableCanvas : Canvas, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //This function should be called when a child element has a property updated.
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    //Create a routed event to indicate when the ObservableCanvas has changes to its child collection.
    public static readonly RoutedEvent VisualChildrenChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "VisualChildrenChanged",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(ObservableCanvas));

    //Create CLR event handler.
    public event RoutedEventHandler VisualChildrenChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(VisualChildrenChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(VisualChildrenChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    //This function should be called to notify listeners
    //to changes to the child collection.
    protected virtual void RaiseVisualChildrenChanged()
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(VisualChildrenChangedEvent));
    }

    //Override to make the changes public.
    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);

        //Create bindings here to properties you need to monitor for changes.
        //This example shows how to listen for changes to the Fill property.
        //You may need to add more bindings depending on your needs.
        Binding binding = new Binding("Fill");
        binding.Source = visualAdded;
        binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        SetBinding(Shape.FillProperty, binding);

        //Instruct binding target updates to cause a global property
        //update for the ObservableCanvas.
        //This will make child property changes visible to the outside world.
        Binding.AddTargetUpdatedHandler(this,
            new EventHandler<DataTransferEventArgs>((object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e) =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("Fill");
        }));

        //Notify listeners that the ObservableCanvas had an item added/removed.
        RaiseVisualChildrenChanged();
    }
}
```

As seen above, this class primarily handles the adding/removing of child elements to/from the `ObservableCanvas`.  You may need to keep a global list of bindings for the elements added, and you may need to consider destroying bindings when elements are removed.

## Code-Behind

Lastly, we need to handle the publicly made notifications so that the target `Canvas` can be updated.  For simplicity, we do this in the `MainWindow`'s code-behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Demonstrate that children added from inside the code-behind are reflected.
        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Orange };
        CanvasSource.Children.Add(newRectangle);
        Canvas.SetLeft(newRectangle, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(newRectangle, 100);

        CanvasSource.PropertyChanged += CanvasSource_PropertyChanged;

        //Also, demonstrate that child property changes can be seen.
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            newRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Brown;
        };
        timer.Start();
    }

    //This event handler is called when a child is added to or removed from
    //the ObservableCanvas.
    private void CanvasSource_VisualChildrenChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCanvas source = sender as ObservableCanvas;
        if (source == null) return;
        CopyElements(source);
    }

    //This event handler is called when a child element of the ObservableCanvas
    //has a property that changes.
    void CanvasSource_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCanvas source = sender as ObservableCanvas;
        if (source == null) return;
        CopyElements(source);
    }

    //This event handler is used to ensure that the target Canvas
    //has the elements copied from the source when initialized.
    private void CanvasTarget_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CopyElements(CanvasSource);
    }

    //This function creates a brand new copy of the ObservableCanvas's
    //children and puts it into the target Canvas.
    private void CopyElements(ObservableCanvas source)
    {
        if (CanvasTarget == null) return;

        CanvasTarget.Children.Clear();  //Start from scratch.
        foreach (UIElement child in source.Children)
        {
            //We need to create a deep clone of the elements to they copy.
            //This is necessary since we can't add the same child to two different
            //UIlements.
            UIElement clone = (UIElement)XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(child));
            CanvasTarget.Children.Add(clone);
        }
    }
}
```

## Final Results

Here is the window upon startup.  It has a copy of the elements in the target `Canvas`.

[image: Window - Run Time]

And since we have a property change occur 2 seconds after initialization (see the code-behind), here is the window after the change occurs:

[image: Window - Run Time After 2 Seconds]